# grpc-java uses Generated annotation from old package

Tags: java, grpc-java, jakarta-migration

We are using Jakarta modules after switching from `javax` to `jakarta` packages.
When I use grpc-java generator, the generated classes contain:

```java
@javax.annotation.Generated(
    value = "by gRPC proto compiler (version 1.35.0)",
    comments = "Source: echo.proto")
```

This does not compile in my project. I cannot add dependency on the `javax` packages, as the library is the same:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and differs in version only (and as such cannot be on the classpath at the same time).

Is there a way to switch to `jakarta.annotation.Generated`, or to remove the annotation from generated source altogether?

Comment: unfortunately google still relies on many `javax` packages: I have similar problems with Guice. With gRPC it's even more complex as it's targeting java 1.7 API, which is coupled with some `javax` packages as far as I remember...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this PR github https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/10927, as they said the release will be part of the 1.63.0 release which is targeted for early April, 2024